# "no method named `map_or` found" when installing deno with cargo

Tags: installation, build, deno

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I had rust already installed using the instructions at rustup.rs in my /home/username/.cargo directory. When trying to install deno with:

```
cargo insall deno
```

towards the end of the process the build fails with the error:

```
   Compiling deno_core v0.47.0
error[E0599]: no method named `map_or` found for type `std::result::Result<&url::Url, &rusty_v8::data::TryFromTypeError>` in the current scope
   --> /home/kaan.atakan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/deno_core-0.47.0/bindings.rs:569:41
    |
569 |     v8::String::new(scope, url.as_ref().map_or("<unknown>", Url::as_str))
    |                                         ^^^^^^ help: there is a method with a similar name: `map_err`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `deno_core`.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `deno v1.0.4`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installuTtprd`

Caused by:
  build failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh! It turns out my rust installation was out of date. I updated it by typing `rustup update` in to the terminal and after the update was finished I ran `cargo install deno` again and everything worked!